# Building realm from Source and using AAR in Android project

Tags: android, realm, android-library, realm-java

I have built the Realm-Java from the source and generated below files as per the [Offlicial-doc](https://github.com/realm/realm-java#building-realm)

- a jar file for the Realm Gradle plugin
- an aar file for the Realm library
- a jar file for the annotations
- a jar file for the annotations processor

Now I used the aar as Module dependency to my app, everything was fine but the Realm libray is dependent on many other libs like “Relinker” , which is not resolved and my app crashes on Realm.init.

Please help me, Is there any working way of using the built realm AAR and JAR files in my Android project, without using maven and jcenter dependency.

P.S: Building from source is mandatory as per my company policy for any 3rd party library.